# Is there a way to test out simple filters before committing to coding them?

Tags: image-classification, tools, image-segmentation

Is there a way to test out simple filters before committing to coding them?

Like if I want to estimate the feasibility of recognizing some features from images. Or to estimate the effort/sophistication of required methods.

Then can I try out something in Photoshop or something in order to discover "where to look for"? Prior to coding?

Answer (score 0):

No - pattern recognition is an empirical field. Each pattern and each system to recognize a patterns has be to be evaluated by implementation.